# Share Seekbar with 3 different variable

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar

I wanted to implement 3 different variable shared with one seekbar. I wanted to know whether is it possible and some pointers?

For example I attached a picture below which is what I trying to do. It's when I select X axis the progressbar change and update to the X axis value.

[image: SeekBar shared with 3 Variable]

instead of purposely create 3 seekbar just to handle x y z variable. That way will used up a lot of space and it doesn't look good in mobile.

[image: 3 seekbar]

Is it possible to implement something like this? Not necessarily must use RadioGroup for this, as long as any method that could make this work will be fine. Any comments and answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the radio buttons with a switch statement with the single progress bar.

Example:

```
int x,y,z;
onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
 switch(radioChecked){
  case x:
   int x = progress;
  break;
  //y and z as well
}
}
```

Any UI logic could be used here, the main things to watch is that variables are initially valid, if ranges for different variables are different adjust the progress bar bounds accordingly, and make sure you update the slider position when you change variables.

Comment: There is something that I don't get it from the sample code. `onProgressChanged` is under `public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int progress, boolean fromUser){` ?

Comment: I wouldn't nest the UI callbacks. Instead, put the swapping logic in the onCheckedChanged and the sliding logic in the onProgressChanged. Something like

onCheckChanged(){
//Swapping logic here - change the indicator variable, change the bounds, and set the progress bar position
}
onProgressChanged(){
//slider logic only here. Use your indicator variable to determine which variable you are saving the result in to
}